# sending emails from a gmail account using django

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, gmail

I have been trying to send an email using my Gmail account but the receiver is not getting anything, why that?

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.core.mail import send_mail


    def index(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            receiver = request.POST.get("receiver")

            from_email = "myemailaddress"
            recipient_list = [receiver]
            subject = "Just sending message"
            message = "If you are seeing this then this possibly worked"

            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False)

        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

settings.py

```
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemailaddress'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'myemailpassword'
```

How do i tackle this problem

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe it's because google doesn't allow non 2fa connections, so you need to use an app password ( google account -> security -> go down to app passwords --> generate new mail password)

Use this new password as your password to connect to your gmail.

Comment: I went there and it asked me to select app and select device before it generates the password

Comment: ok, you are on the right track, select mail app, then for the device just choose custom name, then put anything (like the name of your application), then it will auto generate for you, then save that password as you cant view it anymore after that

Comment: I had this problem once. I fixed it by enabling "less secure apps access" (I believe it's called) in the Gmail account, because I couldn't get the app password to work with Django :| , but that might be an insecure solution for the problem.

Comment: https://wpmailsmtp.com/gmail-less-secure-apps/ google stopped less secure apps since may 30 2022 tho

Comment: by name of application, what if it is not deployed but running on my application

Comment: you can put any name, it does not matter, it just helps you identify what password it is for since you cant view the password. in case you need to delete that password and you need to identify it from the others

Comment: already, i appreciate all this. But i added the password to my EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD variable, i still don't see the message sent

Comment: then i cannot help you since it could then be a very different issue that i am not familiar with